# how to call method with "::" in the first and "->" for the rest in method chaining

Tags: php, oop, static-methods, method-chaining

I want to make my own class that I can use for interacting with a database,
and I think it would be easy and readable if I use method chaining.
But i have a problem calling the first method statically.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

class Crud
{

    protected static $action;
    protected static $instance = null;
    protected static $columns  = [];
    protected $data;
    protected $db;
    protected $query;
    protected $table;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bahan_belajar');
        if (!$this->db) {

            echo "error";
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function select()
    {
        if (empty(func_get_args())) {
            // $this->columns = "*";
            self::$columns = "*";
        } else {
            if (is_array(func_get_args())) {
                // self::columns = join(', ', func_get_args());
                self::$columns = join(', ', func_get_args());
            } else {
                // self::columns = func_get_args();
                self::$columns = func_get_args();
            }
        }

        self::$action = "SELECT";
        return $this;
    }

    public function from($tableName)
    {
        $this->table = ' FROM ' . $tableName;
        return $this;
    }

    public function get($getName = 'object')
    {
        $this->query = self::$action . ' ' . self::$columns . ' ' . $this->table;
        switch ($getName) {
            case 'object':
                $this->data = $this->db->query($this->query)->fetch_object();
                break;
            case 'array':
                $this->data = $this->db->query($this->query)->fetch_array();
                break;
            case 'count':
                $this->data = $this->db->query($this->query)->num_rows;
                break;
        }
        return $this->data;
    }
}

$chat = Crud::getInstance()->select('nama', 'teks')->from('chat')->get();


echo '<pre>';
print_r($chat);
echo '</pre>';
```

Actually, this code works fine if I use `getInstance()` method at first as shown above. But how can I make it work when I call directly to the select() method as a static method like:

```
$chat = Crud::select('nama', 'teks')->from('chat')->get();
```

If I run the code above I will get an error such as:

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\bahan_belajar\chat\classes.php:47 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bahan_belajar\chat\classes.php(74): Crud::select('nama', 'teks') #1 {main} thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\bahan_belajar\chat\classes.php** on line **47**

I know select() method should be a static method before it can be called with `::` (I think), but how can I make it be static?

Comment: You can only use `::` with static methods and `->` with instance methods. You need to get an instance with your static method, then use `->` to chain, like this: `Crud::getInstance()->select('nama', 'teks')->from('chat')->get();`

Comment: yes thanks for commenting. currently i still wondering on how i can applying static on select() method and can be followed with `->` assign for other methods. i still dont know how to solve this :(

Comment: See my more detailed answer. The short version is that it's possible using magic methods to let you pretend instance methods are static methods when you need to, but it's not easy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can only use `::` with static methods and `->` with instance methods. This leaves you with 2 options:

## Option 1: Get an Instance Explicitly Before Chaining

You need to get an instance with your static method, then use `->` to chain, like this:

```
Crud::getInstance()->select('nama', 'teks')->from('chat')->get();
```

## Option 2: Get Fancy with Magic Methods

Your other option is to get fancy with [magic methods](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjm6qf_6f7XAhXjx4MKHe1OBOwQFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Flanguage.oop5.magic.php&usg=AOvVaw3fKhmgR7bqYLli5HQ0WBKK). If you make your methods `protected` or `private`, you can intercept calls to those methods from outside the class with the [`__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) and [`__callStatic()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) magic methods. When you're in [`__callStatic()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic), you can switch over to using an instance by invoking `self::getInstance()`.

This approach would let you do something like

```
Crud::select('nama', 'teks')->from('chat')->get();
```

Here's some very simplified sample code to demonstrate the idea ([demo on 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/g7Kgc)):

```
class Test
{
    public static $instance;
    protected $myVar = 'foo';

    // This intercepts instance calls ($testObj->whatever()) and handles them
    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, $name), $args);
    }

    // This intercepts instance calls ($testObj->whatever()) and handles them
    // The use of self::getInstance() lets us force static methods to act like instance methods
    public static function __callStatic($name, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array(self::getInstance(), $name), $args);
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        return self::$instance ? : new self;
    }

    protected function getMyVar()
    {
        echo $this->myVar;
    }

    protected function setMyVar($value)
    {
        $this->myVar = $value;
        return $this;
    }
}

echo Test::setMyVar(15)->getMyVar(); // successfully echoes 15
```

An important note to all of this: what you are doing looks a lot like reinventing [Eloquent, the ORM that ships with Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent). Take it from somebody who has built his own ORM before: you're better off using an existing system like Eloquent, which has already been written and thoroughly tested (and can be used without requiring you to use the entire Laravel framework). Building an ORM is *much* harder than it looks, and, once you start, the rabbit hole just keeps getting deeper.

Comment: thanks.. its work as expected. i just want to try create my own that i can develop and learn from it :). sorry for not replying on time because something..